# How to display formatted HTML text in dynamic list in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I want to show HTML formatted text in my dynamic list in HTML. However instead of formatted text, the HTML tags are displayed. Here is the code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Water</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to create a LI element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("LI");
  var t = document.createTextNode(" I like <i>Coffee</i>");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Click on Try it button, you will observe that instead of getting formatted HTML i get
I get tags for italics before coffee

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `createTextNode`, you can use `innerHTML` on the element to add text that includes HTML elements, e.g.:

```
  var x = document.createElement("LI");
  x.innerHTML = " I like <i>Coffee</i>";
```

**Working Example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("LI");
  x.innerHTML = " I like <i>Coffee</i>";
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(x);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Water</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to create a LI element.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Reference: [Mozilla Docs for Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)